# Заменить n-элементов списка

Tags: python

Как заменить не последний элемент списка, а сразу три?

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a[-1] = 0
```

Пока только приходит так:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a[-1] = 0
a[-2] = 0
a[-3] = 0
```

А какой самый красивый, компактный и быстрый способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компактно можно через срез:

```
a[-3:] = [0]*3
```

`a[-3:]` - адресует последние 3 элемента списка.
`[0]*3` - создаёт список из трёх одинаковых элементов. Тоже самое, что и `[0,0,0]`.
Ну а дальше одно присваивается другому, т.е. подсписок из последних трёх элементов заменяется на новый подсписок из трёх нулей. В результате `a` станет содержать список `[1,2,3,4,0,0,0]`.

Comment: раз преравали мой ответ, то отвечайте более развёрнуто

Comment: @ganz Я никого не прерывал.

Comment: ну ответил быстрее меня )))) но всёравно можно пример с изменением внутренних элементов по средсвом среза